# Cannibal puzzle

Tags: cipher

You wake up in a dungeon. You see some small letters on the walls. They spell:

> You must get out of here. I have given you a simple puzzle. Here is a code: rw nxu mca ldpmhf "j uium um mhm b fctto". This letter has enough information for you to crack the code. Bye.

Hint 1

> You looks closer and see a PS. It says: `First letters are the key`

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/15632

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking closer, I scream:

> **I WANT TO EAT A HUMAN**

Because

> The first letter of each sentence gives us the key: `YIHTB`. Using this key with a Vigenere decoder gives us the phrase: `to get out scream "i want to eat a human"`

Comment: Good answer, that was great